# ddply - envir must be either NULL

Tags: r, plyr

My script is an R script.
I have this error message :
Error in eval.quoted(.variables, data) : 
  envir must be either NULL, a list, or an environment.
Calls: ddply -> splitter_d -> eval.quoted

```
dataset = read.csv("/home/eby/Documents/Data/train_FD001_01.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
dfrm <- data.frame(dataset)
dataset <- as.matrix(dfrm)

# generate the column RUL (remaining useful life)
library(plyr)

# get the maximum cycle number for each id
d1 <- ddply(dataset,~id,summarise,max=max(cycle))
```

My dataset is :

```
id      cycle
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
2       3
2       4
```

I want to get the maximum cycle number for each id.
My code runs under RapidMiner but not directly in RStudio.

Comment: What's in `dataset` ? What is your expected output?

Comment: I answered you in my post.

Comment: Please restrict your post to a minimum example, also data that you posted doesn't illustrate your question as all id's have `1` for `cycle`. And I don't see your expected output either.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my dataset.

Comment: ddply need a data.frame not a matrix !!!

Good solution :
    d1 <- ddply(dfrm,~id,summarise,max=max(cycle))

This question is not duplicated !!!
The answer don't help me. @henrick